# Adjustable dual voltage level shifter by using a single potentiometer

Tags: voltage-regulator, voltage-reference

I'm very new to the topic but I read that some reference pins of some ICs should not be fed by voltage dividers because of impedance issues.

I need an adjustable +-4V output from an opamp or any suitable IC. The +-4V range adjustment should be done by a single pot. This adjustable voltage will be a reference voltage for the [AD8226](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8226.pdf).

I have +-5V dual power supply to power all the circuit.

Basically I don't want to use heat-sink. I don't know if a voltage reference, voltage regulator or a opamp as a buffer is suitable for such circuit which will not drive much current(such as for a IC ref pin).

The thing is I need to be able to adjust between +4V to -4V just by using a single potentiometer.

**Edit:**

To follow one of the suggestion safely I need an IC which can output both +5V and -5V as below(what is the generic name of such ICs if exists?):

I found this one: http://www.linear.com/product/LT3032 Would it be precise enough for this case? (Oh noo this requires an already dual supply:(()

[image]

Comment: 1 - What are your "raw" input voltages? Do you have +/- 3 volts in, and want each output to vary between 3 (or -3) and zero? 2 - How much current do you need to supply?

Comment: Raw dual supply voltages are +/-5V. I actually need an adjustable output from min -4V to max +4V by using a single IC and a single pot. The output should not exceed 4V or -4V when played with the pot. If not possible I can live with +-3V as well.

Comment: AAAND, the current is what?

Comment: I dont know the quantity but must be too small I guess. I want to use it for the reference pin of this IC:http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8226.pdf. It says For the best performance, source impedance to the REF
terminal should be kept below 2 Ω.

Comment: "I want to use it for a reference pin of this IC." OK, I'll bite. Which IC? Come on, stop dribbling information. Describe your system in detail and make us stop guessing about what, exactly, you need. Details matter.

Comment: I saw some buffer examples either inverting or non inverting but couldnt figure out how to obtain a stable dual voltage adjustment by using a single potentimeter. It says if I use a simple voltage divider it will corrupt the gain of the amplifier. Current sinking by the REF pin not written in the data sheet. Or I couldnt find it.

Comment: Will you please answer the questions I ask? Which IC? A link to the data sheet would be even better - that way we don't have to do your work for you.

Comment: This is so confusing, I have no idea what you're trying to build. You start with "level shifter", after that you actually seem to want a dual-voltage power supply with tracking symmetric outputs, at ±4 volts. Then it's suddenly 3 volts.

Comment: AD8226 http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8226.pdf

Comment: Sorry for the terminology and confusion. I just need adjustable +-4V output from an opamp or any suitable IC. The +-4V range adjustment should be done by a single pot. This adjustable voltage will be a reference voltage for the AD8226.

Comment: You should try to salvage the question by editing in all the new information you have given, people won't read the comments, and they can even be deleted.

Comment: alright i made an edit

Comment: Can you use a stereo pot? It will be one mechanical pot but two electrical interconnected pots inside it.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? I've read the comments and the AD8226 datasheet and I'm more confused. a) Do you need dual voltages (title) or a single +/- voltage (text)? b) The AD8226 takes a single REF voltage, so why would you want two? c) What is the purpose of adjusting the REF voltage between -4 and +4 rather than having a fixed REF voltage? I'm curious as to what you're really trying to accomplish with the circuit.

Comment: In load cells we need to set/zero the offset after we load the load cell. So adjustable offset would be great for that. But for strain gages Im not sure if I need a +- adjustable offset. Im not sure if a strain gage when installed have zero strain on it. I was thinking to make an amplifier which would work for any bridge sensor type application

Comment: Wait, so you don't need dual say 2.5 V and -2.5 V output at the same time, just one ouput spanning from -4 to +4 V?

Comment: Yes thats i need for the REF pin of AD8221. And what Im not sure is this AD8221 is sensitive to REF input and in examples they tie this to GND when used with a dual supply.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you just want something that can produce +-4 V, but it cannot be a voltage divider.

How about using an opamp as voltage follwer, and just use an voltage divider as input? The IC you are using does not seem to require much current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUlM7c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This voltage divider will do the voltage you need.

Comment: If you check the link, this will not do, and is specifically cautioned against in the data sheet.

Comment: You might be right, but i does not see how this differs from the first solution you made. (I understand that it might be a bad idea if got a bad power supply)

Comment: Please read the data sheet. It discusses this.

Comment: No, as i see it, it says that this method is correct. I am not trying to be an ass or anything, i just literally does not understand what is incorrent. My text suggests using a voltage follower after this voltage divider, but is not seen on the schematic (Which might be bad).

Comment: isnt there a single chip precision adjustable dual voltage references in the world?

Comment: @user134429 - 'precision' and 'adjustable' are often oxymorons in electronics. How precisely are you able to adjust the knob on a potentiometer? It'll either be precise and fixed, or adjustable and imprecise.

Comment: But the moment you set it to any value by a pot(it doesn't matter what value of pot as long as the amplifier does not saturate) at least it will stay constant precise voltage at REF during any measurement. This is what I meant by precision.

Comment: @Mathias - Please read the first 3 paragraphs of page 20 of the linked data sheet.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Mathias's circuit is correct, but the schematic is incomplete. Note that in the text he says to feed the output from the divider into an op amp voltage follower, which is exactly what the datasheet recommends. (I missed this at first too.)

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do what you want, but it can be simple or complicated depending on your system. The big question is, how accurate and stable are your +/- 5 volt supplies compared to your variable voltage requirements? If the the answer is that you trust your power supplies, then you can simply do

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWTKOX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, as I say you have to really trust your power supplies. Any noise or drift on these lines will be coupled to the Vref of your AD8226, and this is probably a Bad Thing. Assuming you want bullet-proof, you need something a bit more complicated, such as

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgAQ8N.png)</sup>

Note that R1 and D1 are not specified. They can be a resistor/zener combination or a voltage reference IC. At any rate, the output is inverted by OA1 and the gain adjusted by choosing R3 to give -4 volts. This -4 is applied to one side of the pot. The -4 is then inverted by OA2 to give +4, and this is applied to the other side of the pot. The pot output is buffered as in the simple version.

Comment: I was planning to use a 5V single supply to make a dual power supply by using this converter: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1046fb.pdf So I would have a dual 5V supply. But now you say it matters a lot in this case how good the rail voltages are. Your second circuit suggests 3 opamps in a row. Two questions: 1-) Where is the "single pot" which will make +-4V output in the second circuit, is R3 that pot? 2-) How about using OP4177 in my case which has four OP1177 in one package?:http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/OP1177_2177_4177.pdf

Comment: oh sorry I just saw the pot R6. But I dint get what R3 is about

Comment: Note that R1 and D1 are not specified. What zener value it should be?

Comment: That is up to you. Obviously the zener (if you use one) must be less than 5 volts. Choose one, and determine the resistance based on the specified test current of the zener. But there are also lots of voltage reference ICs which will take 5 volts and give out a very precise and stable voltage such as 1.25 or 2.5 volts.

Comment: The gain of OA1 is -R3/R2. So you need to pick R3 to give a proper -4 volts from whatever voltage reference you pick.

Comment: In load cells we need to set/zero the offset after we load the load cell. So adjustable offset would be great for that. But for strain gages Im not sure if I need a +- adjustable offset. Im not sure if a strain gage when installed have zero strain on it. I was thinking to make an amplifier which would work for any bridge sensor type application

Comment: Please see my edit, is there an IC which is powered lets say any range between from 5V to 12V and outputs precise clean dual 5V and -5V so can be used for dual amplifiers and other references  requires accurate voltages? I would be glad if there is such IC in electronics world?

Comment: @user134429 - No. At least, not that I'm aware of. In order to get -5 from +12 requires some sort of switching regulator, and those by definition produce considerable noise due to switching. Something close to what you want, assuming you can provide +/- 6 volts or more as a raw input is the LT3032 http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/3032fe.pdf  It is up to you to determind if its output is stable enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't specify if you have both positive and negative voltages available and if the rails will be loaded or not. I assume you have load, otherwise see WhatRoughBeast solution.

One can dream up many possible solutions. Here is one over-simplified concept:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFHgfl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

OA2 needs negative supply too.

Other possible solutions include a DC/DC converter, possibly flyback, with two identical secondary windings, one positive and one negative. Regulate on the positive as per usual to your desired pot voltage and make sure the load on both rails are near identical and leakage inductance low and you will have an adjustable +-4 V supply set from a single pot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJJq2d.png)</sup>

Comment: TL 08x op amps will not give 4 volts from +/- 5 volt supply.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast No, they are generic. I'll edit it.

Comment: Yeah, but the point is that "generic" op amps are not rail-to-rail, and you need to specify that. It is unlikely that the poster is aware of the difference.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Well, I'm not feeding him/her a finalized ready for production solution. He/she needs to work out some details too.